# How do 'use' and 'mod' work when there are nested source directories?

Tags: rust

I am having difficulty in building a Rust binary project with multiple nested folders. The intent here is to practice all the examples listed in 'Rust By Example' in one single project and use `cargo run` to see all the output. I have tried various combinations of the `use` and `mod` keywords, but I'm unable to wrap my head around them.

This is the error I get:

```
$ cargo run
   Compiling rustbyexample v0.1.0 (file:///xxx/rustProjects/rustbyexample)
src/main.rs:6:9: 6:11 error: expected one of `;` or `{`, found `::`
src/main.rs:6 mod book::ch01;
```

**folder structure**

```
.
|-- Cargo.lock
|-- Cargo.toml
|-- src
|   |-- book
|   |   |-- ch01
|   |   |   |-- customDisplay.rs
|   |   |   |-- display_list.rs
|   |   |   |-- formatting.rs
|   |   |   |-- mod.rs
|   |   |   `-- tuple_example.rs
|   |   `-- ch02
|   |       `-- arrayandslices.rs
|   |-- coursera
|   |   `-- week1
|   |       `-- caesarcipher.rs
|   |-- lib.rs_neededforalibrary
|   `-- main.rs
`-- target
`-- debug
    |-- build
    |-- deps
    |-- examples
    |-- native
    `-- rustbyexample.d
```

**main.rs**

```
use self::book::ch01;
//use book::ch01::customDisplay::display_example as display_example;
//use book::ch01::display_list::print_list_example as print_list;
//use book::ch01::tuple_example::tuple_example as tuple_example;

mod book::ch01;
//mod formatting;
//mod customDisplay;
//mod display_list;
//mod tuple_example;

fn main() {
println!("Main Rust Program to call others.");

println!("********** Formatting Example   ****************");
formatting_example();
/*
println!("********* Implementing Display Example *************");
display_example();

println!("**** Implement Display to Print Contents of List *****");
print_list_example();

println!("**** Implement Tuple Related Example ****");
tuple_example();
*/
}
```

**src/book/ch01/mod.rs**

```
pub use self::formatting::formatting_example;
   //use book::ch01::customDisplay::display_example as display_example;
   //use book::ch01::display_list::print_list_example as print_list;
   //use book::ch01::tuple_example::tuple_example as tuple_example;

   pub mod formatting;
   //mod customDisplay;
   //mod display_list;
   //mod tuple_example;
```

**src/book/ch01/formatting.rs**

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Structure(i32);

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Deep(Structure);

pub fn formatting_example() {
    println!("{:?} months in a year.", 12);

    println!("{1:?} {0:?} is the {actor:?} name.", "Slater", "Christian", actor="actor's");

    // `Structure` is printable!
    println!("Now {:?} will print!", Structure(3));

    // The problem with `derive` is there is no control over how
    // the results look. What if I want this to just show a `7`?
    println!("Now {:?} will print!", Deep(Structure(7)));
}
```

Comment: Have you read [*The Rust Programming Language*](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book) chapter on [crates and modules](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/crates-and-modules.html)? It contains examples of multiple nested directories.

Comment: @Shepmaster Thank You for pointing me towards that. This topic is part of  Chapter 5 and I have not yet reached there. Code is working as expected. Another plus point, I understood the advantage of having both main.rs and lib.rs in same crate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot use `::` in a `mod` declaration.

You need a file `src/book/mod.rs`, containing:

```
pub mod ch01;
```

And in your `main.rs` file, use:

```
use self::book::ch01::formatting_example;
mod book;
```

Comment: Thanks antoyo. Shepmaster's comment pointed me to the right chapter. Wish that topic was discussed in earlier chapter to avoid this.